# Making a div's overflow:hidden effective without positioning it

Tags: css, html

I have 3 divs:

1. (blue) containing div with `position: relative`
2. (red) div with `overflow: hidden`, floated left
3. (green) div with `position: absolute` that I want positioned relatively to the first div.

see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YgER9/).

I want the green div hidden outside the red div, so making the `overflow: hidden` work without positioning it, because I want the green one positioned relative to the blue one.

I found some similar questions, but none that really fit this same case.

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, but you need to make the red div have **relative positioning**.

Right now, your green div is being positioned absolutely relative to the blue one, but as long as that is happening, it is bound by the overflow rules of the blue one, not the red one.

**When you use absolute positioning, the positioned element is bound by the overflow of the nearest parent element with relative positioning, ultimately the window if no others exist**.

```
.two{
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;

    position:relative;
}
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YgER9/1/)

Comment: the issue is, I want the position context of the green one to be the blue, not the red.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is **impossible** using only css. You could make it look like what your talking about using javascript or jquery fairly easy, but I wasn't sure if you wanted an answer in that form.

Comment: I'd be interested if it's not just applying positioning to the red and negating it with `top` and `left` calculations on the green.

Comment: @climbinghobo I really think that is the only way possible for you to keep it relative to the first div. This would also allow you adjust the divs if you wanted and it would calculate it for you automatically.

Comment: @climbinghobo Just wondering if you have found a solution for your problem else where yet?

Comment: @climbinghobo I think so, at least with just HTML and CSS.